# Why self-initialize reference in initializer list is not an error?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I encountered a strange problem. My compiler (for ESP32) is not showing any error or warning if I try to compile self-assing object reference. I investigate this problem and find out that some compilers will not shown any errors or warnings for this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
    public:
        std::string s;
        Foo(){ std::cout << "Foo()\n"; }
        std::string ToString() { return s; }
};

class Bar
{
    public:
        Foo& foo;
        Bar(): foo(foo) { std::cout << "Bar()\n"; }
        std::string ToString() { return foo.ToString(); }
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    std::cout << "START\n" << bar.foo.ToString() << "\nEND\n";
}
```

Only clang shows a warning about self-assignment but even so it clearly should be an error. Is there any situation that this behavior could be legal?

Comment: [Works with GCC for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/174f7571cca2f9d2) (_works_ in sense: It shows a warning about self assignment, and use of an uninitialzed reference).

Comment: Legal ? Always, I guess. But it'll almost certainly always cause undefined behaviour as well.

Comment: @TheDude But why this is not an error? For ex. compiler will not allow to use pointer in the same manner.

Comment: @Logman Welcome to the wonderful world of _undefined behavior_. Don't worry: It's at least not worse than taking a trip with "Alice in Wonderland". Stay away from the teacups.

Comment: And why the downvotes? Is this question not well written, with an example and a description of the expected and observed behaviour?

Comment: I think you can simplify your whole code to just this, really: `int& x = x;` A reference that refers to itself.

Comment: You could file a feature request with the compiler vendor perhaps. Other compilers do manage to give a warning here

Comment: @NikosC. I agree but my example was not detected on compilers I checked for ex. [this](http://cpp.sh/3adbv) and this trivial one was. But core of my question is why it's not an error?

Comment: *"compiler will not allow to use pointer in the same manner"* [Will too](http://rextester.com/XVKJ62932)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you are right. I was referring to single specific compiler for ESP32 (also in more sophisticated situation) that I checked. Actually that was how we find out our software problem, we swap from references to pointers and get error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any situation that this behavior could be legal?

No. [[dcl.ref]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#5.sentence-3) states:

> A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function.

Your example involves initializing a reference in a way that *doesn't* refer to a valid object, so it's ill-formed. This in general isn't always possible to diagnose for obvious reasons... but here, it's pretty clear that this is an error which is why both [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jAebSTLzgZUEOyIH) and [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jAebSTLzgZUEOyIH) warn about it.

> Only clang shows a warning about self-assignment but even so it clearly should be an error.

The standard doesn't really deal with what's a warning and what's an error. It just deals in diagnostics. Why did these compilers choose to diagnose this as a warning and not an error? Shrug.

Regardless, this is an easy problem to rectify. If you want an error, compile with `-Werror`. And now it *is* an error on both [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RJjgOgh8vOZS93px) and [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nb566FbW1LJ4jImV). This is generally a good habit anyway.

Comment: The standard doesn't require a diagnostic for reference self-initialization , it's a QoI issue. In general it's not possible to detect all cases at compile-time; nonetheless having a warning for simple cases that the compiler can catch seems like a good idea

Comment: @M.M Can you think of any case that compiler can not trace back reference to potential object?

Comment: @Barry in this case you explicit tells to your compiler that you have a valid object under a pointer by deferens it.

Comment: @Logman yeah, global `int& x = foo();` where foo does something complicated or undeterministic in order to decide whether to return `x` or a different static int

Comment: @M.M you hack may question ;). Instinctively, I think it is true. But I tried to find single example of it and I could not.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a compiler refusing to produce an executable for what the standard does not say is ill-formed (as opposed to undefined) would technically be non-conforming, which is why compilers can't default to `-Werror`. The compiler would also have to prove that every possible execution path of your program would invoke this undefined behavior, which is not generally possible.

The standard does not say that your code is ill-formed, just undefined *if you ever invoke this constructor*.

Now you might say, why doesn't the standard declare this to be ill-formed, since it is obviously incorrect? The reason is complexity. The standard is already huge. There are quite a few cases where the standard *could* identify subsets of unconditional undefined behavior that are provable at compile time and make them ill-formed, but doing so would be a very large undertaking and add many more special cases to an already large document.

It is therefore the more practical choice to leave it to compilers to produce warnings in these cases and give the user an opt-in to turn these warnings into errors.

Answer (score 0):

Because self-initializing a reference is undefined behavior, so compilers are free to diagnose messages or not.

[[basic.life]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#2) says

> The lifetime of a reference begins when its initialization is
>   complete.

So the lifetime of `foo` does not begin during the initialization. Then, according to [[expr.type]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1) (emphasis mine):

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression. [ Note: **Before the lifetime of the reference has started or after it has ended, the behavior is undefined (see [basic.life]).** — end note ]

Adjusting the type of `foo` in the initializer expression results in undefined behavior.